# How to run indefinite background process/thread with web application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, glassfish

I want to be able to start/pause/exit a background process from a web application. I want the process to run indefinitely.

A user would go to a webpage. Press a button to start the thread and it will keep running until a user tells it to stop.

I'm trying to determine the best tools to do this. I've looked at things like Quartz but I haven't seen any discussion as to whether or not something like Quartz would be good for an indefinite thread.

My first thought was to do something like this.

```
public class Background implements Runnable{
    private running = true;

    run(){
         while(running){
              //processing 
        }
    }

    stop(){
        running = false;
    }
}

//Then to start
Background background = new Background();
new Thread(background).start();
getServletContext().setAttribute("background", background);

//Then to stop
background = getServletContext().getAttribute("background");
background.stop();
```

I am going to test this out. But I am curious if there may be a better way to accomplish this.

Comment: Was the answer satisfactory?

Answer (score 1):

First, all the `Object`s put into Context must implement `Serializable`.

I don't recommend to put the `Background` object into the context, rather create a `BackgroundController` class, with `private boolean running = true;` attribute. The getter and the setter should be `synchronised`, to prevent that the background thread and the web request thread would conflict. Similarly, the `private boolean stopped = false;` should be put into the same class.

I also made a few other changes, you must break the loop core into small units (like 1 iteration), to make it possible to stop the process somewhere in the middle of the activity.

The code would look like this:

```
public class BackgroundController implements Serializable {
    private boolean running = true;
    private boolean stopped = false;
    public synchronized boolean isRunning() { 
        return running; 
    }
    public synchronized void setRunning(boolean running) { 
        this.running = running; 
    }
    public synchronized boolean isStopped() { 
        return stopped; 
    }
    public synchronized void stop() { 
        this.stopped = true; 
    }
}
public class Background implements Runnable {
    private BackgroundController control;
    public Background(BackgroundController control) {
        this.control = control;
    }

    run(){
         while(!isStopped()){
              if (control.isRunning()) {
                   // do 1 step of processing, call control.stop() if finished
              } else {
                   sleep(100); 
              }
        }
    }

}

//Then to start
BackgroundController control = new BackgroundController();
Background background = new Background(control);
new Thread(background).start();
getServletContext().setAttribute("backgroundcontrol", control);

//Then to pause
control = getServletContext().getAttribute("backgroundcontrol");
control.setRunning(false);

//Then to restart
control = getServletContext().getAttribute("backgroundcontrol");
control.setRunning(true);

//Then to stop
control = getServletContext().getAttribute("backgroundcontrol");
control.stop();
```

Comment: What you should also consider: How do you want to start the `Thread`. In web containers, it is not recommended to start "standalone" threads, better use some Thread pools or `Quartz`.